# Linker Error in iOS (duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64) when running on Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
/Users/inntot/Documents/navigationdrawer 2  2 2 2 2/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework/GoogleInterchangeUtilities(Descriptor.pb.o)
/Users/inntot/Documents/navigationdrawer 2  2 2 2 2/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)

duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
/Users/inntot/Documents/navigationdrawer 2  2 2 2 2/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework/GoogleInterchangeUtilities(Descriptor.pb.o)
/Users/inntot/Documents/navigationdrawer 2  2 2 2 2/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o)

Answer (score 0):

A `duplicate symbol` error means that somewhere in your project being compiled, something that can only be defined once (like a function, const or class) is being defined twice, and hence the name, duplicated, so the compiler is unsure which definition to use.

However, it is highly likely that this is not a problem with you. These particular `symbols`, namely `_llvm.cmdline` and `_llvm.embedded.module`are not generally user-defined symbols and are generally created instead by a framework that you are using, people have encountered this error using frameworks by Twitter and Facebook as well. Looking at the paths to the two files where there are conflicting symbols confirms my suspicion. The errors are being generated in a file in the Google Utils framework.

Firstly, if you made any changes to these google framework files themselves, undo them, as your added or changed code may be the problem.

There are a few fixes that may work for you. The first is that this could be a cocoapods issue. Ensure that you have the default "Debug" and "Release" build configurations in your project, otherwise cocoapods will not handle this well. The next fix that I would suggest is to not include the GoogleInterchangeUtilities framework in the project. GoogleSymbolUtilities was in fact introduced to fix this error cropping up in other google frameworks, so try ONLY including googleSymbolUtilities in your project rather than both symbolutilities and interchangeutilities. Failing that, If there are other versions of these two google frameworks you can download, download a different version, as a fix might have been released or you can find a version before this bug occurred.

If none of these work for you then I would advise getting in touch with google to notify them of this issue, and then sitting tight for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

Project-> Build Settings-> Enabled bit code (change it From Yes to No) i hope it works for you, if it doesn't please check your pods updated or not or if still your facing problem give some details about issue.